I can not pass an array to Airtable create method in Nodejs
I am trying to use Airtable for the first time. I want to simply create a record into a table in Airtable. The record is an array of objects. When I had the data as an object, it went through. But it is a dynamic data and would be in array form, I have not been able to get this to work.
Here is the current code that I am using:
const base = new Airtable({
  apiKey: `${process.env.AIRTABLE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
}).base(`${process.env.AIRTABLE_BASEID}`);

const tempOrderParticipantData = [
  ...(params?.participantData as participantDataAttributes[]),
];

const tempRecord: unknown[] = [];

tempOrderParticipantData?.forEach((item, index) => {
  const getPackage = params?.orderedItemList?.find(
    (m, mIndex) => item?.packageName === m?.orderedItemName,
  );
  tempRecord?.push({
    "Full Name": `${item?.participantNameInfo?.participantFirstName} ${item?.participantNameInfo?.participantLastName}`,
    "First Name": `${item?.participantNameInfo?.participantFirstName}`,
    "Last Name": `${item?.participantNameInfo?.participantLastName}`,
    Phone: `${item?.participantNameInfo?.participantPhoneNumber}`,
    Email: `${item?.participantNameInfo?.participantEmail}`,
    "Tour Name": `${params?.orderDetails?.tripName}`,
    "Tour Start Date": `${dayjs(params?.orderDetails?.tripStartDate).format("MMM/DDD/YYYY")}`,
    "Tour End Date": `${dayjs(params?.orderDetails?.tripEndDate).format("MMM/DDD/YYYY")}`,
    Quantity: `${params?.participantData?.length}`,
    "Tour Price": `${displayCurrency(getPackage?.orderItemPrice as string)}`,
    "Payment Status": `Successful`,
  });
});

base(`${process.env.AIRTABLE_TABLEID}`)
  .create(tempRecord as string[])
  .then((record) => {
    console.log("Created record");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error creating record:", err);
  });

This is the error messsage that comes up when I try to create a record:
Error creating record: AirtableError {
  error: 'INVALID_REQUEST_MISSING_FIELDS',
  message: 'Could not find field "fields" in the request body',
  statusCode: 422
}

